# HttpClient POST request returns status 200 without any body (however it should be). Length of the content is -1

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use Apache HttpClient for POST requests to web service. 
I'm getting

> httpResult=200

however there is no body. I know that some body should be there as **when I
use another POST call method then I'm getting the body in JSON format.**

At this method the length of the response body = -1.

> **response.getEntity().getContentLength()** = -1;
>
> The result of **EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())** is empty string.

The code is:

```
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    JSONObject attributes = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

    attributes.put("201", "Frank");
    main.put("attributes", attributes);
    main.put("primary", "2");

    String json = main.toString();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    httpResult = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    client.close();

    if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

        HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();

        Long length = ent.getContentLength();

        System.out.println("Length: " + length);// length = -1

     }
```

Could anyone give my some hint how to solve the issue?

**In addition** I would like to add the code that gives me a correct response body. At this case I use HttpURLConnection.

```
        HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnect.setConnectTimeout(10000);

        urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        urlConnect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnect.setRequestMethod("POST");

        JSONObject attributes = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject main = new JSONObject();

        attributes.put("201", "Frank");
        main.put("primary", "2");
        main.put("attributes", attributes);

        urlConnect.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnect.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(main.toString());
        wr.flush();

        httpResult = urlConnect.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("Http Result: " + httpResult);

        if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream response = urlConnect.getInputStream(); // correct not empty response body 

            ...
        }
```

Comment: Whats the result of `EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())`?

Comment: The result of **EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity())** is empty string.

Comment: There you go. There is no entity returned in response and so the length is -1. Are you able to get response when using some other http clients?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting the response body for the same request when I use HttpURLConnection. However it is important for me to use HttpClient in my case.

Comment: Can you check whats the content-length mentioned within `Entity`. You can see something like `ResponseEntityProxy{[Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8,Content-Length: 73,Chunked: false]}`. Is the content length is -1 there?

Comment: If I debug HttpEntity ent then I can see an object with wrappedEntity section where the **length** = -1.

Comment: Try by moving `client.close();` after you have done with response.

Comment: Great! That works! Thank you. Please open an answer with this so I can "+" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please move the `client.close();` to the end, i.e., after working with the response.

And to extract the response from `HttpUrlConnection` use the following

```
InputStream response = urlConnect.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line+"\n");
}
br.close();

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); //Converted to JSON Object from JSON string - Assuming response is a valid JSON object.
```